# Piping trimws and gsub in R

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I am able to trim out white space and punctuation in R using the below nested functions:

```
x <- "    a1~!@#$%^&*(){}_+:\"<>?,./;'[]-=    "

y <- trimws(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", x)) #returns "a1" as desired
```

But I'd like to make use of the magrittr / dplyr piping operator (%>%) instead of nesting functions because it makes the code more readable for others, but can't seem to make it work. Here's what I'm trying:

```
x <- "    a1~!@#$%^&*(){}_+:\"<>?,./;'[]-=    "

z <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", x) %>% trimws(x)
```

Here's the error I'm receiving:

> Error in match.arg(which) :    'arg' should be one of “both”, “left”,
>   “right”

This error doesn't make sense to me because leaving out additional arguments to trimws normally removes left and right trailing spaces, so I shouldn't have to specify "both". This error is only thrown when used in conjunction with gsub in the piping syntax.

What am I missing about how piping works? I've reviewed magrittr to no avail.

Comment: Just `gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", x) %>% trimws`.  The function is applied to the output of the previous operation.

Comment: Piping your data in (using `.` to place if necessary) can make your pipeline more readable: `x %>% gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", .) %>% trimws()`

Comment: Fyi, the pipe folks have their own set of functions for this, in the stringr package.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(magrittr)
x <- "    a1~!@#$%^&*(){}_+:\"<>?,./;'[]-=    "   # input

x %>% 
  gsub(pattern = "[[:punct:]]", replacement = "") %>%
  trimws -> z
```